# Excel VBA Macro for Mac doesn't support the same code that was written in Excel for Windows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I wrote the following code in Excel VBA for Windows, and I'm trying to write another version for Mac. I tried everything, but for some reason, the code for Mac doesn't compile. Do people still use Excel VBA these days? Tried asking ChatGPT for a solution but he keeps failing me. Hopefully the help will come from here.

**here is the code:**

```
Sub GenerateExcelDoc()
    ' Define Excel object and workbook
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objWorkbook As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
    objWorkbook.Activate ' Activates the workbook
    Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Set the first sheet as the active sheet

    ' Define source worksheets
    Dim srcSheet1 As Object
    Dim srcSheet2 As Object
    Set srcSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set srcSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Best Practices Guidance")

    ' Copy data from source worksheet to new worksheet
    srcSheet1.UsedRange.Copy
    objSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Auto-fit columns in the new worksheet
    objSheet.Columns.AutoFit

    ' Create a new worksheet for "Best Practices Guidance" tab
    Dim newSheet As Object
    Set newSheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, objSheet)
    newSheet.Name = "Best Practices Guidance"

    ' Copy data from source "Best Practices Guidance" worksheet to new worksheet
    srcSheet2.Cells.Copy
    newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ' Adjust width of columns in the new workbook
    objSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = objSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth + 150
    newSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = newSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth + 150

    ' Adjust the height of column A to be 10 cells high
    objSheet.Columns("A").RowHeight = 1.5 * objSheet.Rows(1).RowHeight
    newSheet.Columns("A").RowHeight = 1.5 * newSheet.Rows(1).RowHeight

    ' Show Excel application
    objExcel.Visible = True

    ' Clean up objects
    Set srcSheet1 = Nothing
    Set srcSheet2 = Nothing
    Set objSheet = Nothing
    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    On Error GoTo Exitsub
    
    If Target.Address = "$B$40" Or Target.Address = "$B$51" Then
        If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo Exitsub
        Else
            If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value
            Application.Undo
            Oldvalue = Target.Value
        
            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
                Else:
                    Target.Value = Oldvalue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: We are not telepathic.  Please explain what your code is trying to do, the error you get and the line on which the error occurs.

Comment: Hello, sorry for that. The file I'm working on has 2 sheets: 1 sheet that gets an input from a user, and the 2nd sheet is "best practices' text.
I'm trying to arrange all the input from the 1st sheet to a new sheet, where all the info is arranged nicely in tables, and a second sheet with a new design of the "Best Practices" sheet. The code gives me an error 438 in line "Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)"

Comment: Instead of Dim objWorkbook As Object - try Dim objWorkbook As Workbook? It's never a good idea to declare objects as "Object". Be explicit.

Comment: Also, Dim newSheet As Object. Should be As Worksheet. I suggest you go through all your As Object declarations and change them to the actual object types you want.

Comment: I suggest you use the same instance of Excel. It will make life a lot easier.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64164983/19353309) the `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` returns a workbook on its own rather than an excel application. Maybe that's the cause of your issue here.

Comment: Please share in which application you will be running this code so we can test it with the correct one. If it is Excel then explain what's with the `As Object` business.

Comment: Please try adding `Set objExcel = objExcel.Application`  after `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` , even if it looks strange... If (in MAC) it returns a Workbook (as `CreateObject("Excel.Sheet"` in Windows), that line should extract the `Application` object, I think. I cannot test it...

Comment: Hello @FaneDuru, this solved the issue! I have no words to thank you

Comment: I must confess that I did not know how `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` behaves in MAC... I found out only now looking to the link placed by @Notus_Panda and I only theoretically thought that the session/application object can be extracted in that way. I never worked in MAC and it is very improbable to ever work, but I think this way of extracting the session object is good to be known by people needing it. So, I placed an answer for such a purpose. No need to mark it as accepted answer, only a comment stating that it works. I think, it may be a guide for ones searching for a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

As [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616784/createobject-excel-application-in-word-2016-for-mac/64164983#64164983), posted by @Notus_Panda, clarifies that (in MAC) `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` returns a workbook, the next way should extract the (COM) `Application` from it:

```
  'your existing code, declarations...
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Debug.Print TypeName(exObj): 'Workbook

   Set objExcel = objExcel.Application 'here the Excel Application object is extracted!!!
   Debug.Print TypeName(exObj): 'Application
  'your existing code...
```

What is interesting is also the fact that this way works well in Windows, too. I mean, no error raised and it can be used to create a macro able to run on both environments: MAC AND Windows...

In Windows, first `Debug.Print TypeName(exObj)` also returns "Application", but his does not bother the next code line, doing the trick in MAC.